# Tools for generating Xaml from System.Windows.Style object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, export

I've got a programmatically generated System.Windows.Style type object and I would like to export that as XAML code, does anyone know of any tools that can do that? It would be sort of like a serialisation, I presume, but I wouldn't like to have to write one myself if there's something out there already.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `XamlWriter`:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(Control));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red));

var xaml = XamlWriter.Save(style);
```

The above code creates this XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="Control"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Style.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Panel.Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush>#FFFF0000</SolidColorBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is actually not that bad! Could I use it from a PowerShell session?

Comment: Actually quite easy to use it from PowerShell:

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter]::Save($myObj)